# Django: populate modal with a form through Ajax

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, modal-dialog

I´m trying to show a prepopulated form in a modal so users can click on an item, the modal opens showing a form with that item´s data that users can edit and save.

I can send data from a view to a modal with json serializer but I can´t find how to send a form.

When I test this, I get an error declaring that `"Object of type FormularioTareas is not JSON serializable"`

The problem seems to be clear, I can´t send the form through a json response. How can I handle this?

Thanks in advance!

**The modal call in the template**

```
 <form name="form" action="#" id="form_tarea_{{tarea.id}}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="id" id="tarea_id_submit" type="text" value="{{tarea.id}}" hidden="true"/>
    <a href="" id="{{tarea.id}}" class="show_tarea" data-toggle="modal" >Este link</a>
 </form>
```

**The Ajax script**

Here I´m using now `$('#caca').text(tarea_data.caca);` only to test I can send some info to the modal correctly. It works.

I guess I should update that "text" type to another one in order to work.

```
    <script>
           $(function(){
                $('.show_tarea').on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    let tarea_id = $(this).attr('id');

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'/catalog/tareas-detail/',
                        type:'POST',
                        data: $('#form_tarea_'+tarea_id).serialize(),
                        success:function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                            $('.show_tarea').trigger("reset");
                            openModal(response);
                        },
                        error:function(){
                            console.log('something went wrong here');
                        },
                    });
                });
            });

            function openModal(tarea_data){
                $('#caca').text(tarea_data.caca);
                $('#modal_tareas').modal('show');
            };
    </script>
```

**The view**

```
def TareaDetailView(request):
    context = {}
    tareas = Tareas.objects.values()
    context[tareas] = Tareas.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        ID = request.POST.get('id')
        tarea = tareas.get(pk=ID)  # So we send the company instance
        tareas_form = FormularioTareas(tarea)
        caca = ID

        return JsonResponse(tareas_form, safe=False)
    else:
        return render(request, 'catalog/artista.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django forms are not json serializable. Either pass your model to json response or return your form as text/json.

`return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', tarea), safe=False)`

Comment: Thanks @sebb, this code you posted is to pass my model as json response, right?

Comment: yes, or try to serialize your form and then you can use jsonresponse with that serialized dict.

Comment: If I don´t understand it wrongly, that way I can send the form data to show it in the template but can´t get the form "active" for the user to edit it and save it, right?

Comment: Best to send send your rendered form in json. So use 'form.as_p()' in your view as send that as your json response.

Comment: form.as_p does not render it in json, it wraps each field in <p> paragraph. No if you send it as json to your ajax, you can do whatever you like to with the response. You can access it in your js

Answer (score 0):

I never use django or phyton before but I will try to help you:

First your ajax, try to use a done insteand of success, in this example you are getting info from some select to fill a form inside a modal with specific

```
function getData(clientId){
  return   $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "YourUrl",
    data: { action: "SLC", clientId: clientId} 
  })
}
```

then you get your stuff:

```
getData(clientId).done(function(response){
//manage your response here and validate it 
// then display modal, note: you must have some conditions to get the array 
//and fill each input use JSON.parse to get the json array elements
 openModal(response);
})
```

hope it helps